# Nested list and parbox

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I am writing a paragraph with the `\parbox` into nested list. My problem is that I want justified the text to the number of main list, and the other hand I want that the nested list is justified to main list.

Can someone help me?

```
%Ejercicio del Tema 2: Formatos en LaTeX

% Clase de documento
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% Configuración para español
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Indicamos el título, autor y fecha
\title{Formatos LaTeX}
\author{María del Carmen Zaballos García}
\date{\today}

% Ajustes del layout
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm, left=4.5cm, right=4.5cm]{geometry}

% Ajuste listas anidadas
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

% La portada se genera con la instrucción siguiente
\maketitle

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\textbf{\theenumi .\theenumii.}}

\begin{enumerate}

%Creación de la Lista-1 y sus listas anidadas
\item El formato de fuente

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Caracteres especiales
    \end{enumerate}

    \parbox[b]{1.05\textwidth}{
    \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} \indent
    \LaTeX {} distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas cuando escribimos instrucciones así que hay que tener cuidado al escribirlas. Por ejemplo \textbackslash LaTeX sirve para insertar el logotipo de \LaTeX en nuestros documentos.
    }

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is unclear to me.  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \begin{enumerate}

%Creación de la Lista-1 y sus listas anidadas
\item El formato de fuente

 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*]
  \item Caracteres especiales
 \end{enumerate}
 
 \parbox[b]{1.05\textwidth}{
 \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} \indent
 \LaTeX {} distingue entre mayúsculas y 

\end{enumerate}

\end{document} Sorry but I don't make a minimal example, I'm new in LaTex. The problem is that I need that the list "1." y "1.1", "1.2", etc are justificated . I hope that you can understand me. Thanks

Comment: Please add the code to the question, not as a comment

Comment: \begin{enumerate}

%Creación de la Lista-1 y sus listas anidadas
\item El formato de fuente

 \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=*]
  \item Caracteres especiales
 \end{enumerate}
 
 \parbox[b]{1.05\textwidth}{
 \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} \indent
 \LaTeX {} distingue entre mayúsculas y\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

Comment: I asked you to put the code into the question above, not as a comment. Now you added it again as a comment ;-)

Comment: \begin{enumerate}

%Creación de la Lista-1 y sus listas anidadas
\item El formato de fuente

 \begin{enumerate}
  \item Caracteres especiales
 \end{enumerate}
 
 \parbox[b]{1.05\textwidth}{
 \setlength{\parindent}{1cm} \indent
 \LaTeX {} distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas cuando escribimos instrucciones así que hay que tener cuidado al escribirlas. Por ejemplo \textbackslash LaTeX sirve para insertar el logotipo de \LaTeX en nuestros documentos.
 }

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

Comment: @MCarmen Carmen, please, insert the code in your text, not as a comment. To do it, click on `edit`, copy the code inside the text and indent every line with 4 spaces. Or select all code and click `ctrl+k`.

Comment: A minimum working example starts with `\documentclass` and includes all packages you use. From your first comment, looks like you are using `enumitem`, then this should be into the preamble of your example.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't show any further document structure, why not use sectional units to denote your "nested list structure":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Configuración para español
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sectsty,indentfirst}
\sectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont\bfseries}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\section{El formato de fuente}

\subsection{Caracteres especiales}

\LaTeX{} distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas cuando escribimos instrucciones así que hay que tener cuidado al escribirlas. Por ejemplo \texttt{\string\LaTeX} 
sirve para insertar el logotipo de \LaTeX{} en nuestros documentos.

\end{document}
```

Sectional units have the advantage that text following it will not be separated from the heading.

Of course, may formatting options are available. I've just set the entire heading font to be **bold**.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!, now it's right. I'm new in the use of latex and I thought that I have to use list to see "1." and into "1.1", "1.2" but justificated the same. I apologize because I haven't good level of english.

Comment: @MCarmen: If this answered your question, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)